# Arduino Class "does not name a type"

Tags: class, arduino

I am currently making a class in order to control 3 DC motors
and in Arduino

and i create 4 object in Arduino (main)
Here is the code:

but when i run this code lot of errors occurs like this

```
'elevator' does not name a type
'elv1' was not declared in this scope
'elv2' was not declared in this scope
'elv3' was not declared in this scope
'elv4' was not declared in this scope
```

So, I would expect some help from people here, regarding how can I make my class work.

Thank you in advance

this is my code

`elevator.h`:

```
#ifndef elevator_H
#define elevator_H

class elevator { 
    public:
        int pos(int swa, int swb,int swc ,int swd);
        void forwardDC(int A11,int A22);
        void reverseDC(int A11,int A22);
        void Breaking(int A11,int A22);
        void stopDC(int A11,int A22);
        char dir;
};

#endif
```

and this is `elevator.cpp`:

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "elevator.h"

int elevator::pos(int swa ,int swb ,int swc ,int swd) {
    int flag =0;
    if (flag >= 4)
        flag = 0;
    if (digitalRead(swa) == HIGH)
        flag = 1;
    if (digitalRead(swb) == HIGH)
        flag = 2;
    if (digitalRead(swc) == HIGH)
        flag = 3;
    if (digitalRead(swd) == HIGH)
        flag = 4;
    return flag;
}

void elevator::forwardDC(int A11,int A22) {
    digitalWrite(A1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(A2, HIGH);
    elevator::dir = 'F';
    delay(1000);
}
```

this declaration in Arduino (.ino):

```
#include <elevator.h>

elevator elv1;
elevator elv2;
elevator elv3;
elevator elv;
```

Comment: TL;DR and format your code too.

Comment: Maybe you should pass an argument to the `#include` directive.

Comment: I'm so sooryI can't understand you . you mean like this #include elv1 ??

Comment: #include <elevator.h>

Comment: where did you save the `elevator.h` and `elevator.cpp` files? If they are in the same directory as the `.ino` you shall include the header using `#include "elevator.h"`. Otherwise, you shall put them in a directory in the `~/Documents/Arduino/libraries` directory (or the equivalent one you use). Your problem means that the arduino IDE is not finding the header (or worst, it finds another header..)

Comment: thanks for your replay, but all 3 extension in the same folder (.h & .cpp & .ino in one folder )

Answer (score 1):

When you use

```
#include <elevator.h>
```

it implies a library from the libraries folder.  Instead, try

```
#include "elevator.h"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the function to create a new elevator variable.
In *elevator.h*:

```
public:
  elevator();
  ...
```

In *elevator.cpp*:

```
elevator::elevator() {
}
```